# Error http 500 php I dont know what I do wrong

Tags: php

I am working on this for the past 1 hour, and I cant get it working...
So, I changed my code to see what he outputs, here is the code changed:

```
<?php

include('../assets/class/usercount.class.php');
include('../assets/class/count.class.php');
include('../assets/class/user.class.php');
include('../assets/class/userupdate.class.php');


$select = $_POST['pick'];
if ($select == 'heads') {
    $select = '1';
} elseif ($select == 'tails') {
    $select = '2';
}
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$balancee = $_SESSION['balance'];
$amountt = $amount - '1';
echo $_POST['pick'] . '<br />' . $select . '<br />' . $amount . '<br >' . $balancee;

?>
```

As output I get:

> heads 1 100 773

That is good, but when I do my whole script on it:

```
<?php

include('../assets/class/usercount.class.php');
include('../assets/class/count.class.php');
include('../assets/class/user.class.php');
include('../assets/class/userupdate.class.php');


$select = $_POST['pick'];
if ($select == 'heads') {
    $select = '1';
} elseif ($select == 'tails') {
    $select = '2';
}
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$balancee = $_SESSION['balance'];
$amountt = $amount - '1';
if (is_nummeric($amountt)) {
    if ($balancee > $amountt) {
        $amount = $amountt + '1';
        $num = rand(1, 2);
        if ($num == $select) {
            $amountt = $amount * '2';
            $balance = $balancee + $amountt;
            update($_SESSION['id'], 'balance', $balance);
            aaron('won', 'up', $amountt);
            header("Location: coinflip.php?message=You have won $amount R$! Your balance is now $balance R$!");
            die();
        } elseif ($num != $select) {
            $balance = $balancee - $amount;
            update($_SESSION['id'], 'balance', $balance);
            header("Location: coinflip.php?message=You have lost $amount R$. Your balance is now $balance R$");
            die();
        } else {
            header("Location: coinflip.php?message=Your input is wrong!");
            die();
        }
    } else {
        $amount = $amount + 1;
        header("Location: coinflip.php?message=Not enough balance! you need $amount R$, you have $balance R$!");
        die();
    }
} else {
    header("Location: coinflip.php?message=Your input is wrong!");
    die();
}

?>
```

Then I get a HTTP error 500, please help me! I am working on this for hours and still nothing works. I cant find the solution :(

Comment: turn on your error reporting. preferably in php.ini or in .htaccess. It seems you suppress error messages now

Comment: @IvoP But I have a webhost with directadmin...

Comment: create a .htaccess file in your document root containing these 2 lines: `php_flag display_startup_errors on` `php_flag display_errors on`

Comment: @IvoP I have added a .htacces file with those 2 lines, I still get error 500...

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should look at apache error log.
Apache log: "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_nummeric () in C: \ wamp \ www \ index.php on line 2"

Is_nummeric () uncorrect, correct "is_numeric ()" :)

Comment: But I have a webhost with directadmin...